# Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession() userPoolTokens is null when shrinking the apk

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk, aws-amplify

I am using the amplify libraries for flutter to connect to my aws backend. After a successful call to `Amplify.Auth.signIn()` I use `Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()` to access the current credentials. Like that:

```
final result = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
  options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true),
);

if (!result.isSignedIn) return const None();

if (result is CognitoAuthSession) {
  return Some(result.userPoolTokens.idToken);
}
```

But when I build an apk with flutter using the following command my code breaks.

```
flutter build apk
```

Because `result.userPoolTokens` is suddenly null and I get a `NoSuchMethodError`. The getter 'idToken' was called on null. But if I disable shrinking and build the apk with the following command everything works again.

```
flutter build apk --no-shrink
```

So I think it has something to do with the shrinking and I would prefer to shrink my app because the shrinked apk is significantly smaller.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to inadequate rules being applied for the R8 shrinker.

The Amplify Android library did not vend any `consumer-rules.pro` until version 1.6.10 (see [release notes](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/releases/tag/release_v1.6.10)), which was just released  January 22nd, 2021.

The latest version of Amplify Flutter is [0.0.2-dev.1](https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_core/changelog#002-dev1-2021-01-25), and it consumes version 1.6.8 of the Android library. I've raised [an issue on their GitHub repository](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/330), to update to 1.6.10.

In the meantime, you could try to apply these rules in your top-level application project.

```
-keep class com.amazon.** { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.** { *; }
-keep class com.amplifyframework.** { *; }
```